# pip installs package to AppData despite admin privileges

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

The title of the question kind of says it all, but here goes.

I'm currently trying to install pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools on my system (not in venv). I have a Python 3.9 installation in `C:\Program Files\Python39`. Usually everything works fine in that, if i have admin privileges pip installs the package to the Python installation and if not it puts it into  `C:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39`. Now I have encountered something strange, even if I have admin privileges and try to install pyqt5 it decides to put it into the AppData Python directory instead of the actual python install inside `C:\ProgramFiles\Python39`.

I know that I could probably fix this by using `-t`, but I am curious as to why it would be this way. Why only PyQt5? Every other package worked absolutely fine until now. I've tried installing random other packages afterwards and they also worked fine. Even PyQt6 was completely normal. So what is it about PyQt5 that makes pip act in weird ways? After about 15 retries and permutations of the install I am still no closer to an answer.

I'm grateful for any explanation at this point, so thank you in advance!